# Mac Mini OSX disk external disk disconnects

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, mac-mini

I have this setup

- Mac Mini Apple M1 8 GB
- OSX Ventura 13.2.1
- Hub Stand for Mac Mini Ssd Sata M.2 Usb-c Usb-a Audio Satechi
- External disk SEAGATE ONE TOUCH 2TB SILVER STKB2000401

I connect the external disk through the Satechi Hub, USB Type C, or USB A. The issue I am facing is that the disk disconnects after a couple of hours.

Comment: Is your Mac going to sleep during this time?

Comment: @Allan, thank you for your question. Not at all; I was watching a video that lasted about an hour, and like at minute 30, it disconnected. Sometimes even if I am not using the computer, I am sure it will not sleep, and it also disconnects.

Comment: Can you plug the drive directly into the Mac to eliminate the hub from the equation?

Comment: @Allan, thank you, I will try that

Comment: Thank you @Allan; you were right; the issue was the hub. It didn't disconnect when I connected the disk directly to the mac, and it didn't disconnect.

Comment: Write up the answer, I’ll upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Allan suggested, the issue was created by the Hub. The disk doesn't disconnect when I connect the external disk directly to the Mac Mini, and the disk doesn't disconnect.

Thank you Allan for your help.